# How can I perform this Yii code in Yii2

Tags: php, encryption, yii, yii2

Actually i need encrypt yii2 url id, like below

example:
from:

```
http://localhost/projectname/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fview&id=20
```

to:

```
http://localhost/projectname/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fview&id=Wmg4T2FZTkNhVjFIMGlrU1ZDUkhMZz09
```

while searching solution for this, i found a solution on Yii.

So how to can convert this code to Yii2.
conifg/main.php

```
'Urlmanager' => [
'rules' => array(
'' => 'site/index', // normal URL rules
array(// your custom URL handler
'class' => 'application.components.CustomUrlRule',
),
),
]
```

and my component CustomUrlRule,

```
class CustomUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule {

public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params, $ampersand) {
$key = "testKey";
return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $route, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
}

public function parseUrl($manager, $request, $pathInfo, $rawPathInfo) {
$key = "testKey";
return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($pathInfo), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}

}
```

This will output -->  http://localhost/projectname/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fview&id=sTK7yXb5Pu22d4n5tbGgT6hwQxhvlrzAe5KWJ0Y4020=

so help me to convert this above code to Yii2

Comment: Please indent your code samples properly

Comment: the above code is my samples, how can i convert that into yii2 format

Comment: You don't need nothing else encoding and decoding the id `int value`. You can create a custom helper that performs this task. However, using one way hashing functions will make difficult to be decoded. So, you have one of two choices, storing the encoded id value in another unique key field in the database, or to not use hashing `md5` for example.

Comment: You are able to use [This Library](http://hashids.org/) and set the length of hashed id to be 32, the encode it using base64 and vice versa to get the id from encoded value.

Comment: **DO NOT USE HASHIDS!** It's not a form of encryption and it sure as hell ain't secure.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually i need encrypt yii2 url id, like below

Are you sure that you want to [encrypt your URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) at all?